# Random Network for Weighted Networks maintaining vertex strength

Tags: r, social-networking

Does there happen to be any existing method for generating a random network for a weighted network with the stipulation that all vertices/nodes in the random network have the same in-strength and out-strength as the real network? Strength being defined as the sum of all outgoing / incoming weights respectively. The randomized weights for each vertex don't necessarily have to be simply shuffled between vertices but can be randomly generated - but there can be no self-loops. i.e. the diagonal of the weighted matrix must be 0.  Weights of the matrix also need to be integers.

Example Matrix

```
mat <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 
1L, 0L), B = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 1L
), C = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 0L), D = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 0L), F = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 15L, 9L, 2L), G = c(2L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 0L), H = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
4L, 2L, 2L), I = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 
0L), J = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), K = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 14L, 3L, 25L, 0L, 1L), L = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 0L)), .Names = c("A", "B", 
"C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"))



  A B C D E  F G H I J  K L
A 0 0 0 1 0  0 2 0 0 0  0 0
B 1 0 1 1 0  0 0 0 1 0  0 0
C 0 2 0 1 0  1 1 0 1 0  0 1
D 0 0 1 0 0  1 1 0 0 0  0 1
E 0 1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0
F 0 0 2 2 0  0 2 0 0 0  3 1
G 1 2 1 1 0  0 0 0 0 1  0 2
H 4 7 4 4 5  6 2 0 5 7 14 5
I 0 2 0 1 1  0 1 0 0 0  3 0
J 5 8 6 2 7 15 3 4 1 0 25 6
K 1 5 6 1 2  9 5 2 4 1  0 2
L 0 1 0 0 0  2 0 2 0 0  1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The following paper has an algorithm to randomize network weights such that the random network is not biased by its structure (i.e. degree). Here's the [paper](http://www.uvm.edu/pdodds/files/papers/others/2006/serrano2006a.pdf)
but it's beyond me to code that. It's the equation 7 and 8